# How to display "x-y products of z" in Shopify collections

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'd like to be able to display the text "Showing 1-24 of 242 products" (or "Showing 25-48 of 242 products" etc.) on each collection page of a Shopify site.

I thought there'd be a simple bit of Liquid code to do this but either my Google-foo is very weak, or it doesn't exist.

Does anyone have a snippet of code they can share to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google-foo somehow missed the obvious, which is a search of the Shopify documentation on how Shopify works. Try this for the answer to your question: 
[Pagination](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/paginate)

Comment: That it did @David Lazar - I had even tried searching the Shopify documentation so not sure how I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have this:

```
 {% if collection.products.size > 0 %}
            <span><h1 class="title">{{collection.title}}</h1></span>  {% if current_tags %}>> {{ current_tags.first }}{% endif %} {{tag}} ({{ paginate.current_offset | plus: 1 }} -
            {% if paginate.next %}
                {{ paginate.current_offset | plus: paginate.page_size }}
            {% else %}
                {{ paginate.items }}
            {% endif %} of {{ paginate.items }})
            {% if collection.description.size > 0 %}
              <p>{{ collection.description }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <h1>{{collection.title}}</h1> <span>{{tag}} (0 results)</span>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the official [Pagination Shopify Docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/paginate).

The following piece of code:

```
Showing items {{ paginate.current_offset | plus: 1 }}-{% if paginate.next %}{{ paginate.current_offset | plus: paginate.page_size }}{% else %}{{ paginate.items }}{% endif %} of {{ paginate.items }}.
```

to output something like this:

Showing items 26-50 of 345.